# regex expression in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

In the following code:

```
 name="DCF3600" id="DCF3600" onclick="toggle3600dcf()" <?php if($row_getInfo3600["DCF"]==1){
```

I am struggling to figure out how to change the two "DCF3600" to "Admin3600". Every line has a different number which I want to keep. The closet I got was

Find: DCF(\d)

Replace: Admin

But this deletes the 3 from 3600. How do I find DCF next to a digit but leave the digit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find DCF next to a digit by searching for

```
DCF(?=\d)
```

The part in parentheses is a look-ahead expression that checks for a digit after DCF, but doesn’t include it in the match.

Answer (score 0):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/TfiCbv/2)

```
\b(?:id|name)="\K\D*
```

Replacement: `Admin`

You can also use either of the following:

```
(?<=")[^\W\d_]+(?=\d+")
(?<=")[a-zA-Z]+(?=\d+")
```

---

### Explanation

- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary
- `(?:id|name)` Match either `id` or `name` literally
- `="` Match this literally
- `\K` Resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match
- `\D*` Match any number of any character except digit

Comment: Simply replace words without regex in your selection. 'name="DCF' by 'name="Admin' and rhe same for the id.

Comment: @MichaelT won’t work if DCF is variable, that’s why I don’t have it hardcoded

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation ctwheels! Unfortunately it doesn't work in my situation since the next line of code is
    name="GA84600" id="GA84600" onclick="toggle84600ga()" <?php if($row_getInfo84600["GA"]==1)

Comment: It does work, but I didn't specify that I have other different variables throughout the document that follow the same format. `\b(?:id|name)="\K\D*` changes them all. Using `DCF(?=\d)` worked best in this situation.